# Kibana Unique count function

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, unique-constraint, kibana-7

I have created a table visualisation so on x-axis I have entity data and on y-axis I am having unique count of traceids function but I am getting unique count of traceids for each entity value is more than the count of records that entity contains . What is the issue and how can I solve

I tried to check how the function unique count is working can I why the unique count value is more

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Its impossible for others to be able to imagine your code and suggest solutions.